# How to add Manufacturer attribute to Filter results in magento layered navigation

Tags: magento

I'm working with Magento Enterprise edition, here by default I'm getting Category's and Price ranges in left navigation bar while displaying products list by Category.

But, I need to add other product attributes like Manufacturer, Transfer type... to the filter results in layered navigation.

I'm able to display that list of Manufacturers under that Manufacturer Attribute but with option 'Filter with no results' with 0 count.

Whenever I changed that option in Admin side for Manufacturer Attribute as `'Filter with results'` under `Catalogue/Attributes/Manage Attributes` I'm unable to see that attribute in front end left navigation bar.

Even though there is assigned lot of products with Manufacturer's. Do i need to make any changes in Code, please help me out I'm new to this magento platform.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try indexing, flushing cache?

Comment: Yes i did that, but no luck

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if sound a stupid question but you changed see the category configuration to be anchor in YES?

I'll keeping you posted after the answer

Best,
Alejandro

Comment: thanks! finally figured out that this was what was missing!!

Answer (score 0):

add this function in your: 
magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php

```
public function getAllManu()
 {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
        ->setEntityTypeFilter($product->getResource()->getTypeId())
                ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', 'manufacturer'); //can be changed to any attribute
        $attribute = $attributes->getFirstItem()->setEntity($product->getResource());
        $manufacturers = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);

        return $manufacturers;
    }
```

Now add phtml file at location:
magento/app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/template/catalog/navigation/left_nav.phtml

```
<?php foreach ($this->getAllManu() as $manufacturer): ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="catalogsearch/advanced/result/?manufacturer[]=<?php echo $manufacturer['value'] ?>"><?php echo $manufacturer['label'] ?></a>
                </li>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

And simply call block:magento/app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/layout/catalog.xml

```
<reference name="left">
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnavigation" template="catalog/navigation/left_nav.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Comment: I tried it, but i need to display the list of manufacturers with counts based on selected products list by category, So the manufacturer's list must be refreshed for every products list

Comment: `add this function in your: magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php`  ? Isnt it BAD to modify Core??